# How do I make a table for historic data?

Tags: python, pandas

How do I make a dataset that shows historic data from snapshots?

I have a csv-file that is updated and overwritten with new snapshot data once a day. I would like to make a python-script that regularly updates the snapshot data with the current snapshots.

One way I thought of was the following:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read csv-file
snapshot = pd.read_csv('C:/source/snapshot_data.csv')

# Try to read potential trend-data
try:
    historic = pd.read_csv('C:/merged/historic_data.csv')
    # Merge the two dfs and write back to historic file-path
    historic.merge(snapshot).to_csv('C:/merged/historic_data.csv')

except:
    snapshot.to_csv('C:/merged/historic_data.csv')
```

However, I don't like the fact that I use a try-function to get the historic data if the file-path exists or write the snapshot data to the historic path if the path doesn't exist.
Is there anyone that knows a better way of creating a trend dataset?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os` module to check if the file exists and `mode` argument in `to_csv` function to append data to the file.

The code below will:

- Read from `snapshot.csv`.
- Checks if the `historic.csv` file exists.
- If it exists then save the headers else dont save header.
- Save the file. If the file already exists, new data will be appended to the file instead of overwriting it.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

# Read snapshot file
snapshot = pd.read_csv("snapshot.csv")

# Check if historic data file exists
file_path = "historic.csv"
header = not os.path.exists(file_path)  # whether header needs to written

# Create or append to the historic data file
snapshot.to_csv(file_path, header=header, index=False, mode="a")
```

Answer (score 0):

you could easily one line it by utilising the mode parameter in `to_csv'.

`pandas.read_csv('snapshot.csv').to_csv('historic.csv', mode='a')`

It will create the file if it doesn't already exist, or will append if it does.

What happens if you don't have a new snapshot file? You might want to wrap that in a try... except block. The pythonic way is typically ask for forgiveness instead of permission.

I wouldn't even both with an external library like pandas as the standard library has all you need to 'append' to a file.

```
with open('snapshot.csv', 'r') as snapshot:
    with open('historic.csv', 'a') as historic:
        for line in new_file.readline():
            historic_file.write(line)
```